# Determinant of a $4\times4$ matrice with one unknown?

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I have to calculate the determinant of this matrice. I want to use the rule of sarrus, but this does only work with a $3\times3$ matrice:
$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 & -6 & u \\
    -3 & 1 & 2 & -5 \\
    4 & 0 & -4 & 3 \\
    6 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
$|A|=35$

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & -6 & u \\-3 & 1 & 2 & -5 \\4 & 0 & -4 & 3 \\6 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{ 3R_1+R_2}{\stackrel{-4R_1+R_3}{\stackrel{-6R_1+R_4}\longrightarrow}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & \;\;-6 & \;\;\;u \\0 & -5 & -16 & \;\;\,3u-5 \\0 & \;\;\;8 & \;\;\;20 &-4u+ 3 \\0 & \;\,12 & \;\;\;37 & -6u+8 \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Now develop the above wrt the first column and you get a $\,3\times 3\,$ determinant. Compute now directly or repeat the above process.

Comment: what do you mean "develope by first colume"? Would you be so kind to explain that further?

Comment: By minors, @maximus. Read it here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Determinant.html

Answer (score 3):

(1)  Expand the determinant with respect to the second column and you will end up with two $3\times3$ determinants.

Or first add two times the second row to the first and then do (1).

Then use the rule of Sarrus.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

$$\det{A} = 2 \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 2 & -5 \\
4 & -4 & 3 \\
6 & 1 & 8 \end{array} \right| + 1 \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -6 & u \\
4 & -4 & 3 \\
6 & 1 & 8 \end{array} \right| $$

which you should easily be able to expand to get a simple linear equation for $u$, which comes out to a nice whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) or the [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). For more an Laplace expansion see [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=louFpVlOhK8) .